# Does permuting user input to variables have efficiency in data storage?

Tags: data-structures, big-o

I recently completed a course in Data Structures and gained new knowledge of storing data such as through linked chains, trees, arrays, and all their various sub-types. However each kind has variations on efficiency to do things with the data such as sorting, finding, or even simple adding and removing of entries from each particular data structure. For simplicity of asking this question, I will keep the method of focus to be traversing a data structure to find a particular entry, which in most average cases is O(n) efficiency*`(see notes)`.

Now in some languages, there exists a technique by which user passed input can be instantiated and used as a new variable within the program. For instance, if I had a method that would do the following 
`myNewVariable("number1 = 1;")`, `number1` would be created with value of 1. *I will not focus on any particular language as this is a question by matter of efficiency, not "if it can be done"*. For sake of this question, say the method that is used to create the new variables has a well defined structure which takes in integers to define new variables. For instance, If a user passed in 1 as input, it would be stored as `number1=1` or if user input is passed as 3, variable would be `number3=3` and so on for however many inputs the user passes. For the sake of this question, we will say the user inputs 100 integers from 1 to 100.

**What I seek to know** is if storing data like this has any efficiency bonus than storing it inside a data structure. From my current software perspective, there appears to be an efficiency bonus in that sorting the data would no longer have purpose as an entry could be found by trying to find if the number exists as a variable already, which would serve as O(1) efficiency when finding a particular entry (all you do is try to find `number#` where # is the actual number). However, from a hardware perspective, it doesn't appear that anything has changed. We have just offloaded more work for the program in question to remember for itself. Data is data, and while it can be compressed and decompressed, a data entry is a data entry, and efficiency would still be in place no matter how large the data actually is.

I want to confirm that I am wrong (or not) In my thinking in that storing data outside of a data structure like an array, a linked chain, or a tree has an efficiency bonus whatsoever. If no response can be achieved here in a timely manner, I will ask my professor about it to see if she knows and share it here.

Notes:

- (For those unaware, O(n) is big O notation which denotes efficiency regarding how effective an algorithm is. The O(x), x being the problem size of how many steps it takes to complete a given function. That said, O(1) is the best possible algorithm that can be achieved as the algorithm completes in one run. As such, O(n^2) is a worse algorithm as that means the problem size is handled more than once.)

Comment: Your question is ... confusing. I can't decide whether you're asking something trivial, or if you're really asking something much more involved. You need to simplify and *clarify* your question. If you restrict your variables to `number1` through `number100`, then of course you can have O(1) lookup efficiency. But if the user can enter `xyzzy=2786`, then you need some other kind of data structure (possibly a hash map) so that you can look up `xyzzy` to get its value. Also, you probably don't need the explanation of O(n), and you certainly don't need the simplistic explanation you provided.

Comment: @JimMischel do you have any suggestions as to how I can make it simpler to understand?

Comment: Eliminate anything unnecessary. Tell us what you're thinking of. *Show examples* of user input and output. Be *specific*. The idea is to tell us everything that's necessary, and eliminate anything else. That's all I can suggest for now, because it's still unclear to me what you're asking.

Comment: Alright. It will take me some time to redesign my question as finals are here.